# Extracting all entries from an autocomplete field into a list

Tags: javascript, node.js, extract

I am trying to extract a full list of all autocomplete entries on a website. The site gives autocomplete suggestions after 1 character and I want to build a list of all the entries.

I know all the entries are company names and is using ng2-completer.

What is the best way of doing this? 
Any suggestions on how to approach this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You have to be getting the data from the server somehow to use in an autocomplete method, so you should already have this data.

Comment: I haven't tried brute forcing because I believe there must be a more elegant solution to this problem. The data i've seen is simply from entering characters into the field

Comment: Do you need to scrape this data from a web page?

Comment: Are you trying to extract data from a website that you don't own or manage?

Comment: I don't have access to the database directly, only through the frontend, but the information is completely public. I simply would prefer to have a list of all the entries locally so I can assess them before conducting the actual analysis.

Comment: Do you know the API URL and param to get the list? Is it accessible for an external call? If not, please, provide the page URL: maybe it can be extracted by some headless browser tool like [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer).

Comment: Yes I got it! I used the API URL to query all the results into a textfile.

Comment: Thanks everyone for all your help!